# If a user posts a question with too much information, is it a good edit to remove it?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently a user posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29569718), which had an awful lot of information that was not really relevant to their real problem. I took it out.

Generally speaking, is removing such red-herring information the right thing to do? It was a much more substantive edit than I usually make – usually my edits are restricted to grammar, readability, indentation, removing “Thanks”… but this edit was actual *substance*, as it were.

Comment: I think your edit was well done in this case. Clear and concise questions attract more answers because someone doesn't have to read a novel to figure out exactly what the OP is asking.

Comment: We all want minimal working examples with a concise description. If you want to help other users achieve that, what is wrong with that? I do that occasionally too, but only occasonially, as it is a lot of work to do correctly.

Comment: You're fine. Any time you can take extraneous information out, the better. Not only does it help focus the question, it also helps more close votes from accruing.

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind is to avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I think that for this particular question, the information was extraneous and was fine to remove.

Answer (score 24):

It was almost a good edit.  You removed the part which described where the ID number is coming from, and therefore changed the meaning of the question.

In its present form, the prima facie answer is "Generate a GUID."  In its original form, the ID could be coming from a database, and it becomes a simple Primary Key concurrency problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to removing much information is to **highlight** or *re-order to the beginning* the key elements of the post.

> Amazing how off-setting the key question (with a question mark) helps?

Information that is the gray area of relevancy can be positioned to a later part of the post.  Blah blah blah ...

Answer (score -2):

What appears irrelevant to you may very well be the entire point of the question. Removing anything except superfluous "thanks" is always dangerous - one reason why I am so hesitant to edit overly long questions.

Better I think, is to add a comment on the question asking the asker to clean up their question.